# Output query data in other format for chart to recognize

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I have a database in which a script extracts sales information from a site.

```
column id name    date            quantity
        1 test 2015-05-14 07:10:07       1
```

All this data is added by date `SELECT DATE("Date"), SUM(quantity) FROM downloads GROUP BY DATE("Date")`  into a chart data
But since I don't have sales/downloads every day I need the date to be added beside the download/sales sum

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row["SUM(quantity)"] . ", ";
}
```

Outputs `1,2,5,6,1,7`  into the chart

In this way I need to output the data in order to be recognized by the chart

```
[Date.UTC(Year,  Month, Day), SUM ],


        [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 1 ],
        [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), 2 ],
        [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18), 5 ],
        [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  2), 6 ],
```

This is what I have right

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        foreach($row as $value){
        echo str_replace("-",", ",$value ." ");
        }
        echo "<br>";
}
```

But it outputs like this

```
2015, 05, 13 2
2015, 05, 14 10
2015, 05, 15 3
2015, 05, 16 8
2015, 05, 17 1
```

Can I get some help to output the date in the right format in order to be recognized by the chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this...

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
   $quantity =  $row["SUM(quantity)"];     
   $datee =  date("Y, m, d", strtotime($row["date"]));
   $ans = "[Date.UTC(" . $datee . ")," .  $quantity . " ]";
   echo $ans . ", <br>";
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: date in /var/www/sum.php on line 26,    $datee =  date("Y, m, d", strtotime($row["date"]));

Comment: this happen before that doesn't get the date because of the sum, this is the table example `downloads` (`id`, `date`, `name`, `quantity`) VALUES
(1, '2015-05-13 23:30:09', 'test', 1),

Comment: use SELECT date, SUM(quantity) in your query

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query to extract the date elements - `Year`, `Month`, `Day` -

```
SELECT YEAR(date) as `year`, MONTH(date) as `month`, DAY(date) as `day`, SUM(quantity) as `sum` FROM downloads GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

and then your loop would be -

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "[Date.UTC(".$row['year'].", ".$row['month'].", ."$row['day']."), ".$row['sum']" ],";
}
```

Comment: On this code while the query works, the output does not print.